# Using DirectX 9; Sprite Anti-Aliasing Halo

Tags: antialiasing, directx-9

So I am coding in DirectX 9 and whenever I place a sprite inside of a 2D world. There is a white colored "halo" that appears around the sprite image p. I am using PNGs and the background behind the sprite is transparent. I have also tried using a pink background as well. It seems that the halo only appears on straight lines of pixels but only on some edges. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
m_d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION); // create the Direct3D interface

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp; // create a struct to hold various device information

ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp)); // clear out the struct for use
d3dpp.Windowed = windowed; // is program fullscreen, not windowed?
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;    // discard old frames
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;    // set the window to be used by Direct3D
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;    // set the back buffer format to 32-bit
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = screenWidth;    // set the width of the buffer
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = screenHeight;    // set the height of the buffer
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;       // automatically run the z-buffer for us
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16; // 16-bit pixel format for the z-buffer

// create a device class using this information and the info from the d3dpp stuct
m_d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                  D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                  hWnd,
                  D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                  &d3dpp,
                  &m_d3ddev);

D3DXCreateSprite(m_d3ddev, &m_d3dspt);    // create the Direct3D Sprite object

LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture;
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(m_d3ddev, "DC.png", D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT,
D3DX_DEFAULT, NULL, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, D3DX_DEFAULT, 
D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 255), NULL, NULL, &texture);

m_d3ddev->BeginScene();

m_d3dspt->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);    // begin sprite drawing with transparency

D3DXVECTOR3 center(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), position((appropriate x), (appropriate y), 1);
m_d3dspt->Draw(texture, NULL, &center, &position, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 255, 255));

m_d3dspt->End();    // end sprite drawing

m_d3ddev->EndScene();

m_d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you screw up your texture co-ordinates from sprite atlasing and you accidentally run off the texture or on to another texture.

Most commonly, anyway, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Um, but what is sprite atlasing?

Comment: Also, by texture coordinates do you mean the x,y coordinates where it is drawn on the screen? I thought that texture coordinates were used when texturing 3D meshes.

Comment: @Peter: Sprite atlasing is where you make more than one sprite on a single texture, and then render part of that texture. It's faster, but getting the texcoords wrong can produce funny results. Texture co-ordinates are used when rendering any texture- 2D or 3D, where 0,0 is the top left (I think) of the texture and 1,1 is the bottom right. If you're using ID3DXSprite then it does this conversion for you, but you still have to specify the right values. If you post an image of your problem, and maybe some basic rendering code, it will aid me in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Hey so I took some screenshots of the issue. And this is also the code I used to load and draw the png.
[IMG]http://i56.tinypic.com/nqa34y.png[/IMG]
[IMG]http://i53.tinypic.com/2z65n4n.png[/IMG]

Comment: @DeadMG
Here is the code to load and draw the png
`LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture;
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(m_d3ddev, "DC.png", D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT,
D3DX_DEFAULT, NULL, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, D3DX_DEFAULT, 
D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 255), NULL, NULL, &texture);

D3DXVECTOR3 center(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), position((appropriate x), (appropriate y), 1);
m_d3dspt->Draw(texture, NULL, &center, &position, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 255, 255));`

Comment: sorry for the horrible formatting, but on a side note we are also not using atlasing were are drawing the entire image.

Comment: @Peter: You really need to edit that into your question, I can't read that in the comment.

Comment: @DeadMG Oh duh, I just did it

Comment: @Peter: I don't see any device or sprite init code. When I said "code", I meant, "Pretty much everything that happens between and including BeginScene()/Present()".